# Changing "Enter title here" based on post format

Tags: title, post-formats

I'm wondering if is possible to change the text "Enter title here" based on the post format that you selected? For example: If you select the post format **Quote** than your text will be "Enter author's quote". Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the following;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    $('input.post-format').click(function(){

    $('#title-prompt-text').val( $(this).next('label').text());

    })

});
```

This will replace the title with whichever post format you select.

Save the above into a file called **`custom-post-title.js`** and you will need to place this file into your theme folder. Either in the root or within a folder named `/js/` - but just note that if you put it within a sub-folder make sure that you reflect this within the next snippet I give you.

Then in your theme **`functions.php`** file you need to enqueue your script for use in the admin area and in this case we will enqueue it on the post/page edit screens only (so it doesn't unnecessarily load elsewhere and create overhead.

```
function custom_post_title($hook) {
    if( 'edit.php' != $hook )
        return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_post_title', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/custom-post-title.js', __FILE__) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_post_title' );
```

Usuing **`admin_enqueue_scripts`** filter means we are only injecting our Javascript file on the backend (admin area) not on the front end, after all its useless to your users.

If you want to add a little further customization and change the default post title then use (also within your **`functions.php`** file);

```
function custom_title( $title ){

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( 'post' == $screen->post_type ) {

    $title = 'Choose your post format';

    }

    return $title;

}

add_filter( 'enter_title_here', 'custom_title' );
```

This is something similar to what Rutwick posted above previously; although this does not address your immediate question, it does extend the level of customization so you can have,

- A default post title upon entering the edit screen
- The post title dynamically updated upon the selection of a post format.

Good luck!

Notes:

I've made an important update to the jQuery, by modifying;

<s>**$('#title-prompt-text').text( $(this).val());**</s>

In favor of,

**$('#title-prompt-text').val( $(this).next('label').text());**

The former was grabbing its property from the "value" attribute of the input field and while this is perfectly fine to do in most cases, WP assigns the "Standard" `post_format` a `value=0` instead of `value=Standard` - for all other `post_formats` the value is equal to that of its name.

The reason for this is because WP returns `false` when for example using the API function `get_post_format()`; thus this is how it decides to determine its default standard post. Which is a bit silly really, so the latter adjustment takes care of that by grabbing the value of the `input` fields adjacent `<label>` element instead which contains the name of our post format needed.

Answer (score 0):

Go for jQuery! You can do this via php, but only when you are editing a post, for which you've already set the post format. But for 'Add New', you cannot, because the post format is not set.

Comment: No, it's not post type. I'm need the function for the post format.

Comment: Oops... missed that part... wait let me check...

Comment: You have to do some jQuery for it! Because my function works on `$post` object, which does not have the post format.

Comment: So when either of the radios is checked, change the place holder text.

Comment: Exactly! That's is the idea.

Comment: How good are you with jQuery? You can write a script, enqueue it for the `post-new.php` file only.

Comment: Can you provide an example?